# Can we use $y * \operatorname{sgn}(\hat y)$ as a loss function in linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear, loss-functions

Can we use $y * \operatorname{sgn}(\hat y)$ as a loss function in linear regression where $\hat y$ is the prediction and $y$ is the target value, or is there any other loss function close to this which can be used?

Comment: You likely would find it illuminating to plot a graph of this function (or a contour plot).

Comment: Do you mean something like $L(y, \hat y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[y_i \times sign(\hat y_i)\right]?$ // I changed your notation to be more consistent with how statisticians use $x$ in a regression setting.

Comment: Out of a collection of functions $\{f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_i, \cdots\}$, how would you decide which one is the *closest* to another function $g$ when there exists a possibility of multiple functions in $S$ that are measure-zero distant from $g$?

Answer (score 4):

In regression, where you want to approximate the measured points $(x_i, y_i)$ with those from your estimator $(x_i, \hat y_i)$, a loss function should be a function involving some kind of distance between $y_i$ and $\hat y_i$, like e.g. the norm of the residual $\hat y_i - y_i$.

In your case, you have only one $y$-value in your loss, so, unless something is missing, this would not compare the measured data with the estimated data, i.e. it doesn't measure any loss.

So, the answer is: No, this is not a sensible loss function.

Answer (score 2):

**For a loss function to work effectively, its smallest values should occur where $y \approx x.$**

Such small values are shown in dark blues in this filled contour plot of the standard quadratic loss function $\mathcal{L}(x,y) = (y-x)^2.$

[image: Figure 1]

Visually, *you want the colors surrounding the diagonal line $y=x$ to be dark blue.*

Here is a comparable plot of $\mathcal{L}(x,y) = y\operatorname{sgn}(x):$

[image: Figure 2]

The dark blues occur where $x$ and $y$ are *large* and *of opposite signs.*  This will not be an effective loss function unless you want your predictions to be as far away from the true values as you can possibly make them!

---

I hope it's now clear that any function that comes even close to this one will not be a useful loss function.  But at least you now have a rapid, reliable visual procedure to evaluate any candidate loss function you might care to think up.  To make this as easy as possible to do, here is `R` code to produce a plot of a loss function.

```R
#
# Create an array of losses.
#
loss <- function(x, y) y * sign(x)
y <- x <- seq(-1, 1, length.out=201)
z <- outer(x, y, loss)
#
# Plot its values and the reference line y == x.
#
col <- rev(rainbow(13, 2/3, 1)[1:10]) # The color scale red ... blue
image(x, y, z, col=col, main=bquote(paste("Contours of ", .(body(loss)))))
contour(x, y, z, add=TRUE)
abline(0:1, lwd=2, col=gray(.25))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's exemplify with a bivariate normal distribution with $\vec{\mu} = \vec{0}$ and $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -0.9 \\ -0.9 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Import libraries.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
```

Generate data set.

```py
cov = [[1,-0.9],
       [-0.9,1]]
x,y = np.random.multivariate_normal(
    [0,0],
    cov=cov,
    size=1000).T
x = tf.reshape(tf.constant(x), (-1,1))
y = tf.reshape(tf.constant(y), (-1,1))
```

And let's define your loss function.

```py
def sign_product_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.matmul(y_true, tf.math.sign(y_pred), transpose_a=True)
```

Define a simple linear model (slope and intercept as parameters).

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.Input(
            shape=(1,)
            ),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=1,
            activation=None
            )
        ]
    )
```

For training, I selected the Nadam (Nesterov-accelerated adaptive moments) just b/c I find it a reliable default for toy problems. Other optimizers would also work excellently on this simple linear regression problem. In Tensorflow we must compile the model.

```py
loss = sign_product_loss
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam()

model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    loss=loss
    )
```

Now train the model.

```py
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=100)
```

If we look at the loss history, we can see that the model did not obviously trend toward better or worse fit.

[image]

And plotting the predictions and the original data together, we can see that the resulting fit was not acceptable.

[image]

---

One way to study an objective function is to plot the contours of its surface over its input. See [whuber's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/568995/69508) for an explanation. As a supplement to that answer, here is some quick Python code to produce filled contour plots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def loss(x,y):
    return y * np.sign(x)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(-1,1,200)]*2)

Z = loss(X,Y)


fig, axes = plt.subplots()
g = axes.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap='rainbow', levels=15)
##g.clabel(fontsize=10, inline=1, fmt='%.1f', colors='k') # Labels if you want them
axes.plot(*[[-1,1]]*2, color='k')
axes.text(-0.05, 0.05, '$y = x$', rotation=45)
axes.set_xlabel('x')
axes.set_ylabel('y')
axes.set_title('$y \\times \\operatorname{sign}(\\hat y)$')
axes.set_aspect('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The above can be adjusted as desired, but currently outputs:

[image]